# Python create a function with a chain within

Tags: python, function

I come from R and we love pipes, it makes really easier to understand the code and I try to apply it as mucha s I can. However, I'm trying to create a function that do many operations in a string. They work individually but when I try to set them as a chain into the function, they do not work:

```
def funtest(df, x):
    (
        df
        .replace({x: {'ä': 'ae', 'ö': 'oe', 'ü': 'ue', 'β': 'ss'}}, regex = True, inplace = True)
        .replace({x: '\s{2,}'}, ' ')
        .replace({x: '^\s+'}, ' ')
        .replace({x: '\s+$'}, ' ')
    )
    return df

 funteste(df, 'strings')
```

[image]

Can anyone show me how I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Do not set `inplace=True` for [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) if you want chain as it then does

> performs operation inplace and returns None.

Just assign result back, consider simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['A','B','C','D','E']})
df = df.replace({'x':{'A':'a'}}).replace({'x':{'C':'c'}}).replace({'x':{'E':'e'}})
print(df)
```

output

```
   x
0  a
1  B
2  c
3  D
4  e
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your fixed code:

```
def funtest(df, x):
    return (
        df
        .replace({x: {'ä': 'ae', 'ö': 'oe', 'ü': 'ue', 'β': 'ss'}}, regex = True)
        .replace({x: '\s{2,}'}, ' ')
        .replace({x: '^\s+'}, ' ')
        .replace({x: '\s+$'}, ' ')
    )

 funteste(df, 'strings')
```

I've done 2 things.

1. Removed the `inplace=True` that was making your code fail because the next operation was running on a Nonetype.
2. changed the return place since we are no longer operating inplace, we need to return the result of all operations.

Is this good for you?